# Set custom Wordpress REST-API URL

Tags: wordpress, rest, apache

I'm running an regular WordPress instance on an apache2 Debian server. For the frontend I'm using an react spa with the REST-API of the WordPress backend.
Now, I've changed the URL of the frontend to separate it from the WordPress backend with:

```
/** SITE SETTINGS
 */

define('WP_HOME','https://frontend.foo.bar');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://backend.foo.bar');
```

The problem is, that the rest API calls are now made from **frontend.foo.bar/wp-json/...** For instance, when I'm trying to update an existing post, I've receive the message:

> "Updating failed. You are probably offline."

Is it possible to somehow modify the API domain?
There is a `rest_url_prefix` but it changes only the part after the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your theme's functions.php. It will perform a similar prefix replacement, but will completely replace your home_url with siteurl and will not result in the error **"Updating failed. You are probably offline"**

```
function custom_rest_url( $url ) {
    $new_url = trailingslashit( get_option( 'siteurl' ) ) . 'wp-json';

    $url = str_replace( home_url( '/wp-json' ), $new_url, $url );

    return $url;
}

add_filter( 'rest_url', 'custom_rest_url' );
```